# Button to restart app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I've been making an app that I need help with. After I do what I want the app to do, it goes to a new page. when I press the go back button, it is still in the same state as when I left. I want the first view to completely reset when I hit the button. Any suggestions as to how to do this? Any help is appreciated!

Here is code for what the button currently does:

```
- (IBAction)retry:(id)sender 
{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You will need to create an IBAction in the first view controller, and then call that action either right before or after you dismissModalViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Implement viewWillAppear on your initially displayed viewController as following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //
    //put your code to reset this viewController into its initial state here
    //
    [self resetAllStatesBackToDefault];
}
```

As an example, suppose you got a `UITextField` on that first viewController that is named `textField`;

```
- (void)resetAllStatesBackToDefault
{
    self.textField.text = @"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;`